# Issue with Send As/On Behalf of another User

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Afternoon,

I know this question has been posed a billion times (I have read every link on the first 12 pages of google).

We have a user who has her primary email (AD User). She sends on behalf of 3 other users. She has full access along with send on behalf access. She does not have her name in Send As Permission.

She wants to send email as the 3 other accounts and have them show up in the users mailbox without showing On Behalf of. She just wants the email and name of the user to show. This has worked flawless for 2 years. Today that all stopped.

I spent 3 hours screwing with it and between all the changes I made I managed to make the 1st of 3 email addresses to send properly. But honestly don't know what I did since I made so many changes and tests.

I cannot for the life of me figure out the last 2 email addresses. They will not show up with just their name. I tried to remove send on behalf permissions and just do Send As permissions but I constantly get undeliverables because the user doesn't have send on behalf permissions (whats the point of Send As then).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand your issue.
For example, user A B C,
Do you mean that you want A send on behalf B to C, but only show B to C?

If so, as I know, only Send As permission could help achieve this.
Full Access could allow the delegate to open the mailbox, and view, add and remove the contents of the mailbox, but  doesn't allow the delegate to send messages from the mailbox.
Send on Behalf  Allows the delegate to send messages from the mailbox or group. The From address of these messages clearly shows that the message was sent by the delegate ("  on behalf of ")
For more information, please check this article: [Manage permissions for recipients](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019).